# Maximum possible length of string literal in C

Tags: c, standards

What is the maximum possible length of string literal in C? If I am not wrong, In Java and .NET, maximum possible length is `2^31 - 1`.

Comment: Depends on platform, runtime environment, compiler, does that include Unicode?

Comment: If you need to know, you are probably doing something wrong. But if you really really need to know, it's at least 4095. A compiler is allowed, but not required, to accept more than that.

Comment: Why don't you just try it out?

Comment: @SpiderPig: Because knowing the limit imposed by one particular compiler is less useful than knowing what the language requires.

Comment: http://port70.net/~nsz/c/c11/n1570.html#5.2.4.1

Answer (score 6, accepted):

There is no specified upper bound on the length of a string literal.

The standard requires all implementations to support string literals of at least 4095 characters after concatenation, but compilers are free to support arbitrary long string literals. (The requirement in C90 was 509 characters; C99 increased it to 4095.)